# There isn't any maximal finite subgroup of a multiplicative group of a division ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, division-algebras

It is an exercise in division algebras and I couldn't find the answer:

> Suppose that $D$ is a division ring. Prove that $D^{\times}$ has no finite maximal subgroup.

Comment: Isn't $\mathbb F_9$ a counterexample? The group of units is the cyclic group of order $8$, so it has a cyclic group of order $4$ which is maximal. I guess I could be misjudging what you mean by "maximal" or some other assumption... please let me know.

Comment: You are right but suppose that $D$ is infinite and we should solve it for infinite case.

Answer (score 1):

Let $D$ be a division ring. If $D$ is finite, then by Wedderburn's Theorem, $D$ is a field and then $D^\times$ is cyclic and has a maximal subgroup (take the non-generating elements, since these are finite, one among them must be maximal). So the statement does not hold. In the case where $D$ is infinite, I have no found a coherent method that would solve the problem. After doing some reading, this seems to be an open research question. See the following papers for more:

[ON MAXIMAL SUBGROUPS OF THE MULTIPLICATIVE GROUP OF A
DIVISION ALGEBRA](http://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/lag/man/260.pdf)

[ON THE MULTIPLICATIVE GROUP OF A DIVISION
RING](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1957-008-02/S0002-9939-1957-0083984-8/S0002-9939-1957-0083984-8.pdf)

[SUBGROUPS OF THE MULTIPLICATIVE GROUP
OF A DIVISION RING](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1966-124-01/S0002-9947-1966-0201508-9/S0002-9947-1966-0201508-9.pdf)

Comment: It is an open problem that the infinite division ring has a maximal subgroup. you can see this in Mahdavi-Hazavei's papers.

Answer (score 1):

This is not answer but I state following easy lemma. It may help us.

> Let $G$ be group and $M$ be a maximal subgroup of $G$. Then either $Z(G)\subseteq M$ or $G'\subseteq M$.

Now, if $(D^*)' \subseteq M$, then $M$ is a normal subgroup. Hence, there exists a prime number $p$ such that $[D^*:M]=p$. Since $M$ is finite, $D$ is finite too.

So we can assume that $M$ contains center of $D$. If $D$ is a finite dimension algebra on its center, then we can conclude that $D$ is finite.